# IPv6 default gateway route disappear after reboot

Tags: ipv6, gateway, route

I'm using Debian Wheezy on a dedicated server which uses IPv4 and IPv6 at the same time.

**ifconfig eth0**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 11:11:11:11:11:11  
          inet adr:90.0.0.1  Bcast:90.0.0.255  Masque:255.255.255.0
          adr inet6: fe80::21c:c0ff:feb9:829c/64 Scope:Lien
          adr inet6: 2001:a100:1:bbbb::1/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1544 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2199 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000 
          RX bytes:304146 (297.0 KiB)  TX bytes:1376282 (1.3 MiB)
```

(Several minutes later, the RX dropped counter increases.)

**cat /etc/network/interfaces**

I first used the "gateway" keyword, but it didn't work, so I then tried to add the route in the file, but it didn't work either.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 90.0.0.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 90.0.0.0
    broadcast 90.0.0.255
    gateway 90.0.0.254

iface eth0 inet6 static
    address 2001:a100:1:bbbb::1
    netmask 64
#   gateway 2001:a100:1:bbff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    up ip -6 route add ::/0 via 2001:a100:1:bbff:ff:ff:ff:ff dev eth0
    down ip -6 route del ::/0 via 2001:a100:1:bbff:ff:ff:ff:ff dev eth0
```

**ip -6 route show**

These are the routes shown several minutes after rebooting the server.

```
2001:a100:1:bbbb::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256 
2001:a100:1:bb00::/56 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256  expires 2591959sec
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256 
default via fe80::224:c3ff:fe84:400 dev eth0  proto ra  metric 1024  expires 1759sec
default via fe80::224:c3ff:fe84:800 dev eth0  proto ra  metric 1024  expires 1759sec
```

**Questions**

1. **Why isn't my default route taken into account** (no matter using keyword `gateway` or `ip -6 route add` in the `/etc/network/interfaces`, **during boot time**?
   Note that if I add the route manually, it works perfectly and I can TX and RX to and from the Internet using IPv6. (The problem is to make it automatic.)
2. What are those strange kernel routes, that will expire? Do I need them? My server is connected directly to the same network as a rooter (2001:a100:1:bbff:ff:ff:ff:ff), which is itself connected directly to the internet.

**EDIT**

**ifdown --force eth0; ifup --verbose eth0;**

```
Configuring interface eth0=eth0 (inet)
run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
ip addr add 90.0.0.1/255.255.255.0 broadcast 90.0.0.255       dev eth0 label eth0
ip link set dev eth0   up
 ip route add default via 90.0.0.254  dev eth0 
run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/avahi-daemon
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/bind9
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/mountnfs
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/ntpdate
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/openssh-server
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/openvpn
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/postfix
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/upstart
Configuring interface eth0=eth0 (inet6)
run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
modprobe -q net-pf-10 > /dev/null 2>&1 || true # ignore failure.


sysctl -q -e -w net.ipv6.conf.eth0.autoconf=0
ip link set dev eth0   up
ip -6 addr add 2001:a100:1:bbbb::1/64  dev eth0 
 ip -6 route add default via 2001:a100:1:bbff:ff:ff:ff:ff dev eth0 
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth0.
```

Comment: I am confused `2001:a100:1:bbff:ff:ff:ff:ff` is not on the same network as `2001:41D0:2:4F51::1`.  Those are different networks.  Can you ping `2001:a100:1:bbff:ff:ff:ff:ff` without the gateway set?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I just updated. Yes, I can ping it when the route is not set.

Comment: IPv4 address `90.0.0.1/24` and gateway `90.0.200.254` are on different networks, as are `2001:41D0:2:4F51::1/64` and `2001:a100:1:bbff:ff:ff:ff:ff`. The default routes you see (the `fe80:` addresses) are learned from Router Advertisements (`proto ra`). Your configuration makes no sense, so it is no surprise that it doesn't work...

Comment: I also just corrected the IPv4 mistakes. There were just obfuscation mistakes!

Comment: If you do an `ifdown --force eth0`, followed by an `ifup --verbose eth0`, do you see any output or errors?

Comment: I just added the output of this command.

Comment: Don't configure a /56 on an interface, always use a /64

Comment: The thing is, I didn't configure it, and don't know where it does come from. This route appears automatically after reboot, as well as other strange routes (which will all expire).

Comment: I've checked my config, and I am pretty sure you are getting 2001:a100:1:bb00::/56 gateway address from your router as part of the IPv6 auto-configuration handshake.  I notice you disabled net.ipv6.conf.eth1.autoconf, but you also need to disable net.ipv6.conf.eth1.accept_ra, if you want to completely turn-off IPv6 auto-configuration. (ref: http://superuser.com/questions/33196/how-to-disable-autoconfiguration-on-ipv6-in-linux)

Answer (score 3):

Possibly these `sysctl` settings might help you?

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf=0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra=0
```

Answer (score 2):

The following configuration in /etc/network/interfaces works for me:

```
iface eth0 inet6 static
     address 2001:a100:1:bbbb::1
     netmask 64
     up ip -6 route add default via 2001:a100:1:bbff:ff:ff:ff:ff
     down ip -6 route del default via 2001:a100:1:bbff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```